# Make G-WAN's Ruby to use JRuby

Tags: ruby, jruby, g-wan

How to make G-WAN's Ruby to use JRuby Instead of Ruby, this is what i've tried:

```
$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
$ cd /usr/bin
$ mv ruby ruby2
$ ln -s `which jruby` ruby
$ ruby --version
jruby 1.7.4 (2.0.0) 2013-05-16 2390d3b on OpenJDK Client VM 1.7.0_40-b31 +indy [linux-i386]
$ ruby2 --version
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [i686-linux]
```

but when i install Ruby, this message shows up (this doesn't show before):

```
test.rb: to use   .rb scripts, install Ruby
```

the purpose was so i could possibly use Java's `import api.Gwan` (`include_package api.Gwan`), since there are no (or i'm not yet found it on the docs) API provided to Ruby (to access the cookie, access the KV, etc)

**EDIT**: ah, i don't think this would be useful -_-", since not a full API implemented on GWAN's Java

```
package api;
public class Gwan {
  public static native long getReply(long paramLong);
  public static native void xbufCat(long paramLong, String paramString);
  public static native long cycles64();
  public static native long getNs();
  public static native long getUs();
  public static native long getMs();
  public static native void logErr(long paramLong, String paramString);
  public static native void report(long paramLong, int paramInt);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> attempt to replace Ruby by JRuby

This won't work as is because G-WAN is checking if the ruby runtime is available by invoking ruby and checking the program reply.

We could add JRuby detection however. But the proper way to use Ruby might be its embedding interface in C (if there's any). If you are interested in such a solution then please drop us a line with the proper information (code sample would be great).

That's the way we have implemented C, C++, D, Objective-C, C# and Java.

Regarding the partial implementation of the G-WAN C API for Java and Scala, that happened for two reasons:

- many G-WAN functions will no longer be fast once wrapped in JNI (with the data conversions that come with it)
- very few Java or Scala developers are seeking to use high-performance replacements for the well-known and widely used Java libraries, so there was little demand (at least so far).

Ruby and a few other languages have been implemented as CGI either because we did not find how to do it otherwise or because, like for PHP, the documentation and code that we have found just did not work in G-WAN's multithreaded environment.

We welcome the assistance of seasoned users in these languages that we don't master.